# WebSocket connection getting rejected in production when using docker container

Tags: django, docker, websocket, redis, django-channels

My WebSocket connection getting rejected from the Django Channels server deployed in AWS EC2. I am using Docker for server side which contains PostgreSQL and Redis also

```
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/notifications/
WebSocket REJECT /ws/notifications/ 
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/notifications/
```

[image: error in the ubuntu server]

front-end is built using React Js  is deployed in netlify.
server side is secured using cer-bot.

my **nginx** configuration files looks like this

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}
server {
    server_name IP_address example.com ;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /staticfiles/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/social-network-django-server;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/_____; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/____; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name IP_address example.com ;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

everything other than the websocket connection is working fine without any issues. I have no idea what is happening here. I am using d]Django channels first time,

I am using `wss://` instead of `ws://`

my error in the browser looks like this

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://_____________________' failed:
```

if any one have any idea what is happening please share!

my github repo links [server](https://github.com/Jauharmuhammed/social-network-django-server) [client](https://github.com/Jauharmuhammed/social-network-react-client)

my **Dockerfile** looks like this

```
FROM python:3.11.1

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        postgresql-client \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

my **docker-compose.yaml** looks like this

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=2221
      - POSTGRES_DB=social-network
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
      - "5432"

  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:2221@db:5432/social-network
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379/0

  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379"

volumes:
  db-data:
```

I think this is maybe related to redis, can someone explain what is this error is all about, I am new to Redis and first time I'm using it

my websocket connection is rejected by server in the production environment.

most of the time it is getting rejected, but one time I got the error like this

```
future: <Task finished name='Task-2137' coro=<Connection.disconnect() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/asyncio/connection.py:720> exception=RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/asyncio/connection.py", line 729, in disconnect
    self._writer.close()  # type: ignore[union-attr]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/streams.py", line 344, in close
    return self._transport.close()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 839, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 761, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 519, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
```

[image: error]

Comment: I've noticed in your code there are several places where you have `ws://` as opposed to `wss://`, (for example, https://github.com/Jauharmuhammed/django-react-chat-app/blob/4c7a36398f0475601f18c9aa14ff3923069013e4/frontend/src/contexts/NotificationContext.tsx).  Could this have anything to do with it?

Comment: @raphael  thank you for your time, but that is not the one I am currently working on, this one [here](https://github.com/Jauharmuhammed/social-network-react-client ) is the link to the frontend, I replace all ```ws://``` with ```wss://```